# Installed Lodash with ReactNative, app crashed

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, lodash

I installed lodash with react native and the app immediately crashed.

Now I cannot complete a successful build.

This is the error that I receive:

```
warn Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure the React Native CLI. Migration guide: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually: 
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-reanimated (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-reanimated")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Found Xcode project "news_arg_frontend.xcodeproj"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -project news_arg_frontend.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme news_arg_frontend -destination id=A1A8090A-EB7F-4794-99FA-DF5F02FE5C82 -derivedDataPath build/news_arg_frontend")
.....
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening news_arg_frontend.xcodeproj. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend

Build Preparation
Couldn't create workspace arena folder '/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend': Unable to write to info file '<DVTFilePath:0x7f925a17d0e0:'/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/info.plist'>'.
Couldn't update module cache session file '/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation': You don’t have permission to save the file “Session.modulevalidation” in the folder “ModuleCache.noindex”.


2019-07-21 18:16:17.387 xcodebuild[28551:5087832] couldn't read dependency graph from '/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/dgph': Permission denied
2019-07-21 18:16:17.387 xcodebuild[28551:5087832] unable to create temporary file at /Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/dgph-jq6yCUic: Permission denied
2019-07-21 18:16:17.389 xcodebuild[28551:5087832]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14098/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/DependencyGraph/XCDependencyGraph.mm:688
Details:  unable to write dependency graph: Permission denied
Object:   <XCDependencyGraph>
Method:   +loadOrCreateInBuildDirectory:withTargetBuildContext:withBasePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f925a057910>{number = 9, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2019-07-21 18:16:17.390 xcodebuild[28551:5087831] couldn't read dependency graph from '/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jsi.build/dgph': Permission denied
2019-07-21 18:16:17.391 xcodebuild[28551:5087831] unable to create temporary file at /Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jsi.build/dgph-2aBd8ZsF: Permission denied
2019-07-21 18:16:17.391 xcodebuild[28551:5087831]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14098/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/DependencyGraph/XCDependencyGraph.mm:688
Details:  unable to write dependency graph: Permission denied
Object:   <XCDependencyGraph>
Method:   +loadOrCreateInBuildDirectory:withTargetBuildContext:withBasePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f925a057840>{number = 8, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2019-07-21 18:16:17.393 xcodebuild[28551:5087833] couldn't read dependency graph from '/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jsinspector.build/dgph': Permission denied
2019-07-21 18:16:17.393 xcodebuild[28551:5087833] unable to create temporary file at /Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/jsinspector.build/dgph-TxCPNDUd: Permission denied
2019-07-21 18:16:17.393 xcodebuild[28551:5087833]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-14098/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/DependencyGraph/XCDependencyGraph.mm:688
Details:  unable to write dependency graph: Permission denied
Object:   <XCDependencyGraph>
Method:   +loadOrCreateInBuildDirectory:withTargetBuildContext:withBasePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f925a164520>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **

2019-07-21 18:16:17.723 xcodebuild[28551:5087849] Error saving log: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Logs/Build/8F1803F2-22FC-430A-91E1-956D257F96A9.xcactivitylog, NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied} | User info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/news_arg_frontend/ios/build/news_arg_frontend/Logs/Build/8F1803F2-22FC-430A-91E1-956D257F96A9.xcactivitylog";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Permission denied";
}
```

At this point I've uninstalled lodash, tired a build and the problem still exists.

EDIT:
My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "news_arg_frontend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^1.0.1",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.1.9",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.28",
    "aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.15",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose-deep-populate": "^3.1.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native": "^0.60.4",
    "react-native-comments": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-custom-checkbox": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-modest-checkbox": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.18.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^4.0.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router-native": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rex": "^0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

There was some question around the path given to lodash.

Comment: how did you install? could you have upgraded react-native while installing?

Comment: I ran `npm i --save lodash`, then it said `found 13127 vulnerabilities (11 low, 1 moderate, 13115 high)`. I ran `npm audit fix`, then it went up in smokes.

Comment: So you shouldn't blame lodash then. You ran a command that installs dependencies. I bet one of those was react-native with a version less than `0.60`. If you read that error message it says... `This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above.`

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, this is definitely my fault. any idea on how to track it down?

Comment: I'm not saying its your fault or well to pass blame, that wouldn't be productive :) What I meant was that its misleading, and makes it harder for us to help. thats all. To fix your issue you need to follow the instructions. You have manually linked packages, you need to unlink them

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I unliked the packages, but still get the same error of `We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65`